# Joomla 2.5 Admin menu translation issues

Tags: joomla-2.5, administrator, language

I am currently busy debugging an extension a colleque wrote. That means I have not full knowledge of how the extension works, and my limited experience with Joomla does not help me with a little problem I encountered.

The extension has an entry in the admin menu, however the menu entry is not translated and uses a placeholder alias from the database... that is until I click the menu link. As long as the menu item is active, the translation works correctly.

I looked and see that the language files are there and apparently correctly configured, the language folder is tagged under files in the manifest file, too.

Has anyone a hint for me where that strange incoherence could come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla extensions have generally two translation files: en-GB.com_myextension.ini and en-GB.com_myextension.sys.ini.

- en-GB.com_myextension is loaded automatically when the extension is executed.
- en-GB.com_myextension.sys.ini is loaded automatically always to show information about the extension (name and description), when the main file is not loaded, for instance to show it in the menu.

In addition, an extension may have more extension-specific language files.

Comment: That's it. The menu translation was in the main file but not in the sys.ini. Thank you very much.